# How to retrieve and display login user data

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get data and display from MS sql server? The connection between database and application was completed. How can I add query and display? I was wondering or anyone get any links to teach these can post it.

```
TextView txtuserid, txtusername, txtcompany, txtposition, txtdob;
SharedPreferences shp;
ConnectionClass connectionClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    txtuserid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtuserid);
    txtusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
    txtcompany = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcompany);
    txtposition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtposition);
    txtdob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdob);

    shp = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Profile.this,
                Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        LogOut();
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Profile.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void LogOut() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shp.edit();
    edit.putString("UserId", "");
    edit.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: You just need some JDBC code to do this, or possibly an ORM framework like Hibernate if you are feeling more sophisticated.  But I don't see any database code above.  Where did you do you database coding work?

Comment: i havent add database code in this activity because i wondering should put at where... can u help me?

Comment: If you are intending to hit a SQL Server database somewhere in the cloud, then you will have to make a REST call to a web application somewhere, and from there do the SQL query.  If you want to hit embedded SQLite running on your phone, that is another, slightly less complicated, story.

Comment: noted thanks ur help

Comment: So maybe try to narrow down your question so that someone may answer it.